# REST services do not work in custom mapped directory on Coldfusion 10 server

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, restful-architecture

I am new to REST API. I am trying to convert web application to REST-ful with an updated site design.

My work environment on development server is Coldfusion10, Windows 2008 R2 Server.
So far I successfully registered REST services to web root directory of ColdFusion 10 server and it works fine.

However, I need to register REST services in the site's directory. I have done so and it worked couple of times but, most of the time I am receiving 500 error after I edit the CFC (changing string in `cfreturn` from "foo" to "foo2"). I verified syntax of the CFC by going directly via url and, its ok. 
I tried to add REST services in Administrator and, most of the time I get errors when adding in Administrator like this:

```
•Unable to refresh REST service.
Application rc could not be initialized.
Reason: The application does not contain any rest enabled CFCs.
The application does not contain any rest enabled CFCs.
```

I added web services in the Application.cfc

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
  <cfset this.name = hash(getCurrentTemplatePath()) />
  <cfset this.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan( 0, 0, 1, 0 ) />

  <cffunction name="onRequestStart" access="public" returntype="boolean" output="false" hint="I initialize the request.">
    <cfset restInitApplication("E:\flex\html\v4\rc","rc")>
    <cfreturn true />
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

This is the /rc/studentHandler.cfc

```
<cfcomponent restpath="student" rest="true">
  <cffunction name="getMethod" access="remote" output="false" returntype="string" httpmethod="get">
    <cfreturn "foo">
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

And the last file is student.cfm. I call it from `http://mydevip/v4/student.cfm`

```
<cfhttp url="http://mydevip/rest/rc/student" method="get">
<cfoutput>#cfhttp.filecontent#</cfoutput>
```

I tried to call cfc directly from url which works if cfc in the CF web root folder `http://mydevip/rest/rc/student` and, gives me error if I call cfc in custom directory.

Here is the error from application.log

```
"Error","ajp-bio-8012-exec-5","11/13/13","10:13:30","5C89BF4E37081433800CEF0D961170B0","object is not an instance of declaring class The specific sequence of files included or processed is: E:\flex\html\v4\rc\studentHandler.cfc'' "
```

Thanks,

Gena

Comment: This looks almost identical to the question you asked yesterday (and have since deleted). If you don't get answers to your question I'm not sure asking it again will make any difference.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: I evaluated CF10's REST features and had serious problems (I think like the ones you describe, but it's been a while) if my CFCs were anywhere other than the application's root. I quickly gave up on CF10's REST support and hand-write what I needed. Have you looked at http://atuttle.github.io/Taffy/

Comment: Yesterday, I started testing by registering REST services in the custom directory and, was not successful so, I thought may be I am missing something. Then, I registered in CF web root and it worked. Therefore, at least one part of the question is answered and, I know REST services work on my dev server. So, I rephrased my question and deleted the old one.

Comment: barnyr, so, it is not workable at all? I want at least to start from learning basics without diving into frameworks.

Comment: Dont initialize rest in onRequestStart. You may use onApplicationStart and use HTTP call to initialize that application not a rest call. Also when you change any CFC refresh the rest app. Its because CF's rest works on stub-skeleton model(Internally through JAX-RS) and application lifecycle is run after stubs/skeletons are generated, and you are refreshing stubs with onrequeststart by calling restinitapplication. And maybe the exception "object is not an instance of declaring class" is because of that. Also changing CFCs refreshes skeleton, so stubs also need to be refreshed